# Table formatting different after div tag

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><Select ></select</td></tr>
</table>
<div>
</div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Class</td>
<td><select></select></td></tr>
</table>
```

However I see the table after the div gets different formatting , as compared to the first table before div.

For Example if we see in browser it looks like:

Name----------Select List(`- represents space`)

Class-- Select Combo

**The formatting for the select combo for class is quiet different , it gives less space as compared to the first table.I have not applied any styles for table.**

**Inserting div inside the table is not possible.**
**Note : Spaces are specified by -**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `<td>` in `<tr>`; so try to modify your code to this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><Select></select></td>
  <tr>
</table>
<div>
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Class</td>
    <td><Select></select></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks , I forgot to add that

Comment: I could have accepted but the problem is not that you specified to me.

Comment: @Chetan I said "an answer" not "my answer"! that you did that!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not give your tables and columns a specific width, they will just grow to the size of their content

you should style them using css:

**Fixing you markup and adding classes:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="title">Name</td>
    <td class="input"><Select ></select></td>
  <tr>
</table>
<div></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="title">Class</td>
    <td class="input"><Select ></select></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
table {width:100%;}
table .title,
table .input {width:50%;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hJWRg/)

However I would have to say that tables are for tabular data so you shouldn't really be putting the breaker div in there (or even using tables as that doesn't look like tabular data)